# Como validar campos editText vacíos cuando son muchos campos Android

Tags: android, android-studio, edittext

Tengo en mi actividad exactamente 96 campos editText, lo que quiero saber es como validar que ninguno esté vacío, para el caso de uno tengo el siguiente código, alguno de las dos opciones:

```
String precio= this.precio.getText().toString();

 if (precio.equals("")) {
 Toast.makeText(this, "Ha dejado campos vacios", 
         Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
 }


String precio= this.precio.getText().toString(); 
 if (TextUtils.isEmpty(precio_coste) {
 Toast.makeText(this, "Ha dejado campos vacios", 
         Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Cómo lo hago si tengo que validar muchos campos al mismo tiempo. Gracias.

Por ahora estoy validando en el if con (or), pero quiero saber si existe una manera más simplificada:

```
if (dat_1.equals("")||dat_2.equals("")||dat_3.equals("")||dat_4.equals("")||dat_5.equals("")||dat_6.equals("")||dat_7.equals("")||dat_8.equals("")
                    ||dat_9.equals("")||dat_10.equals("")||dat_11.equals("")||dat_12.equals("")||dat_13.equals("")||dat_14.equals("")||dat_15.equals("")||dat_16.equals("")
                    ||dat_17.equals("")||dat_18.equals("")||dat_19.equals("")||dat_20.equals("")||dat_21.equals("")||dat_22.equals("")||dat_23.equals("")||dat_24.equals("")
                    ||dat_25.equals("")||dat_26.equals("")||dat_27.equals("")||dat_28.equals("")||dat_29.equals("")||dat_30.equals("")||dat_31.equals("")||dat_32.equals("")
                    ||dat_33.equals("")||dat_34.equals("")||dat_35.equals("")||dat_36.equals("")||dat_37.equals("")||dat_38.equals("")||dat_39.equals("")||dat_40.equals("")
                    ||dat_41.equals("")||dat_42.equals("")||dat_43.equals("")||dat_44.equals("")||dat_45.equals("")||dat_46.equals("")||dat_47.equals("")||dat_48.equals("")
                    ||dat_49.equals("")||dat_50.equals("")||dat_51.equals("")||dat_52.equals("")||dat_53.equals("")||dat_54.equals("")||dat_55.equals("")||dat_56.equals("")
                    ||dat_57.equals("")||dat_58.equals("")||dat_59.equals("")||dat_60.equals("")||dat_61.equals("")||dat_62.equals("")||dat_63.equals("")||dat_64.equals("")
                    ||dat_65.equals("")||dat_66.equals("")||dat_67.equals("")||dat_68.equals("")||dat_69.equals("")||dat_70.equals("")||dat_71.equals("")||dat_72.equals("")
                    ||dat_73.equals("")||dat_74.equals("")||dat_75.equals("")||dat_76.equals("")||dat_77.equals("")||dat_78.equals("")||dat_79.equals("")||dat_80.equals("")
                    ||dat_81.equals("")||dat_82.equals("")||dat_83.equals("")||dat_84.equals("")||dat_85.equals("")||dat_86.equals("")||dat_87.equals("")||dat_88.equals("")
                    ||dat_89.equals("")||dat_90.equals("")||dat_91.equals("")||dat_92.equals("")||dat_93.equals("")||dat_94.equals("")||dat_95.equals("")||dat_96.equals("")
                    ||dat_97.equals("")||dat_98.equals("")||dat_99.equals("")||dat_100.equals("")) {
                Toast.makeText(PollaMundialista.this,"Faltan campos por llenar",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(PollaMundialista.this,"Todos los campos están llenos",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
```

Comment: Si tuvieras esos 96 campos almacenados en un array, creo que si se podría hacer una validación a través de un método de una manera mas o menos sencilla.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para lograrlo solo tienes que obtener todos los editText que contiene tu layout, recorrerlos y evaluar su texto. Como hacerlo? fácil.

1. Primero obtienes el layout que contiene los editText.

   ```
   LinearLayout linearLayout = findViewById(R.id.ll);
   ```
2. Después con el método `getChildCount()` del layout obtienes el número de EditText que contiene el layout. Este número lo utilizaras para recorrer los editText.

   ```
   int count = linearLayout.getChildCount();
   ```
3. Después recorrer los editText que contiene el layout utilizando un `for`. Los editText que contiene el layout los obtienes con el método `getChildAt()` de éste.

   ```
   for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
       EditText editText = (EditText) linearLayout.getChildAt(i);
   }
   ```
4. Y por último evalúas el texto que contiene cada editText utilizando un `if`. De esta manera sabrás si quedan editText vacíos o no.

El siguiente ejemplo muestra como se vería este código implementado.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Obtienes el layout que contiene los EditText
    LinearLayout linearLayout = findViewById(R.id.ll);

    // Obtiene el numero de EditText que contiene el layout
    int count = linearLayout.getChildCount();

    // Recorres todos los editText y si hay alguno vacio cambias el valor de la
    // variable isAllFill a false, lo que indica que aun hay editText vacios.
    boolean isAllFill = true;
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {

        // En cada iteración obtienes uno de los editText que se encuentran el
        // layout.
        EditText editText = (EditText) linearLayout.getChildAt(i);

        // Compruebas su el editText esta vacio.
        if (editText.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
            isAllFill = false;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (isAllFill) {
        Log.i("MainActivity", "onCreate -> else -> Todos los EditText estan llenos.");
    } else {
        Log.i("MainActivity", "onCreate -> if -> Hay EditText vacios.");
    }

}
```

**Nota:** Ten en cuenta que he suponido que tienes los editText dentro de un LinearLayout y que dentro de éste solo tienes editText. A pesar de esto, este código se puede adaptar fácilmente a cualquier situación. Cualquier duda que tengas déjamela en los comentarios.

Comment: Muchas gracias David

Answer (score 2):

También me animo.
Bueno tenemos nuestros `EditText`

```
EditText dat_1, dat_2, dat_3, dat_4...;
```

Los almacenos en un array

```
EditText[] misCampos = {dat_1, dat_2, dat_3, dat_4};
```

Creamos un método para hacer la validación de los campos, y nos devolverá **true** si encuentra alguno vacío, y **false** si están todos rellenos

```
public boolean validarCampoVacio(EditText[] campos){

        for(int i=0; i<campos.length; i++){
            String cadena = campos[i].getText().toString();
            if(cadena.trim().isEmpty()){
                return true;
            }

        }
        return false;
    }
```

Y ya como último paso sería mandar llamar al método cuando queramos hacer la validación.

```
if (validarCampoVacio(misCampos))
```

---

Te paso un Ejemplo al completo..
**MainActivity**

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
        EditText dat_1, dat_2, dat_3, dat_4;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            dat_1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.dat_1);
            dat_2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.dat_2);
            dat_3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.dat_3);
            dat_4 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.dat_4);
            final EditText[] misCampos = {dat_1, dat_2, dat_3, dat_4};

            Button btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn);
            btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (validarCampoVacio(misCampos))
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Faltan campos por llenar",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    else
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Puedes continuar", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });

        }

        public boolean validarCampoVacio(EditText[] campos){

            for(int i=0; i<campos.length; i++){
                String cadena = campos[i].getText().toString();
                if(cadena.trim().isEmpty()){
                    return true;
                }

            }
            return false;
        }

}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias Diego

Comment: Gracias a ti. Saludos!